# gcp nodejs error 500

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I get the following after deploying an update to my nodejs app. I've stipped the app back to basic hello world and still shows the same. Page will sit there for 5mins looking like its loading them show the following.

It also throws up 4 or 5 instances as well even though I am only trying to access it once.

Please help why is this happening?
Thanks,
John

---

Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.

Please try again in 30 seconds.

Comment: In which port your `node.js` app is running?

Comment: process.env.PORT || 8080

Comment: Which gcp service are you using ?

Comment: just trial using the free tier

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Did you solve this in the end?